# Unchecking the checked checkboxes while scolling the list in Android?

Tags: android

My problem is list of checkboxes are there which are checked in gridview , while scrolling  the list, those checked one is turned to unchecked one.

Comment: Yeah sure, if you explain your question properly.

Comment: Problem is 10 checkboxes are there in a list, among them 4 are checked and while scrolling the list, those ckeckboxes which previously checked one becoming unchecked one... This is the Problem..

Comment: Code and xml would help.

Answer (score 1):

Shiva,

If you are using custom Adapter for your list,then you can implement an ArrayList to keep track of the CheckBox State. And in your getView() function of Adapter, set your CheckBox true/false according to the ArrayList. This is a starting point for your problem. I hope you can figure out the rest. If you still have any problem, you can ask.

Comment: Assume that we have a ListView with CheckBox and other controls in each row. Now we make our own ArrayAdapter by Overriding its getView() function. Now, we have to keep track of all the check boxes with the help of an ArrayList<Boolean>, which will tell us that which check box is checked or unchecked. Initially, this ArrayList will be set to all false entries(unchecked). Then, in your getView() of Adapter, set the checkbox according to this ArrayList. This getView() is called automatically for each row of ListView. And you can change the values of ArrayList in your onListItemCleck() function.